# is there a way to add characters in between separators in a text file?

Tags: sed

I have an input file (customers.txt) that looks like this:

```
Name, Age, Email, 
Hank, 22, hank@mail.com
Nathan, 32, nathan@mail.com
Gloria, 24, gloria@mail.com
```

I'm trying to have to output to a file (customersnew.txt) to have it look like this:

```
Name: Hank     Age: 22   Email: hank@mail.com
Name: Nathan   Age: 32   Email: nathan@mail.com
Name: Gloria   Age: 24   Email: gloria@mail.com
```

So far, I've only been able to get an output like:

```
Name: Hank, 22, hank@mail.com
Name: Nathan, 32, nathan@mail.com
Name: Gloria, 24, gloria@mail.com
```

The code that I'm using is

```
sed -e '1d'\
    -e 's/.*/Name: &/g' customers.txt > customersnew.txt
```

I've also tried separating the data using `-e 's/,/\n/g'\` and then `-e '2s/.*Age: &/g'`. It doesn't work. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed & column):

```
sed -E '1h;1d;G;s/^/,/;:a;s/,\s*(.*\n)([^,]+),/\2: \1/;ta;P;d' file | column -t
```

Copy the header to the hold space.

Append the header to each detail line.

Prepend a comma to the start of the line.

Create a substitution loop that replaces the first comma by the first heading in the appended header.

When all the commas have been replaced, print the first line and delete the rest.

To display in neat columns use the column command with the `-t` option.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using awk for this? Like:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=", ";OFS="\t"} NR==1 {split($0,hdr);next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=hdr[i]": "$i} 1' file
Name: Hank      Age: 22 Email: hank@mail.com
Name: Nathan    Age: 32 Email: nathan@mail.com
Name: Gloria    Age: 24 Email: gloria@mail.com
```

This simply saves headers into an array and prepends each field in following records with `<header>:`.

Comment: The OP will probably want to add `| column -s $'\t' -t` since they appear to want visually-tabular output instead of tab-separated output.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=", "
  OFS="\t"
}
FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    value[i]=$i
  }
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    $i=value[i] ": " $i
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above solution.

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                        ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=", "                     ##Setting field separator as comma space here.
  OFS="\t"                    ##Setting output field separator as TAB here for all lines.
}
FNR==1{                       ##Checking here if this is first line then do following.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){         ##Starting a for loop to traverse through all elements of fields here.
    value[i]=$i               ##Creating an array named value with index variable i and value is current field value.
  }
  next                        ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){         ##Traversing through all fields of current line here.
    $i=value[i] ": " $i       ##Setting current field value adding array value with index i colon space then current fiedl value here.
  }
}
1                             ##1 will print all lines here.
'  Input_file                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: That's the same as @oguzismail's answer but using a loop to populate the header array instead of just calling split().

Comment: @EdMorton, Thanks Ed sir, I noticed that now, am thinking to use single for loop and each time it checks either line is first line or not and either create array or re-create field but then it needs to check unncesaary each time that condition, so dropped that thought as of now.

Comment: Yeah, I've considered that in the past too for this type of problem but, as I'm sure you figured out, it'd be too unnecessarily inefficient to test `FNR==1` once per field per line vs just once per line.